# Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEEB176B2F (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll)

Tags: c++, error-handling, sfml

I have looked at similar questions but none of them refer to my issue.

I am doing this all in debug and not release, and using the correct -d files.

I keep receiving this error - Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEEB176B2F (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in OOSD_Group_Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000028.

What could this be?

Thanks

---

[Photo of where exception is thrown:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQV1.png)

The class from where exception is thrown:

class spritesAndTextures {
private:
//declare textures
sf::Texture playerTex;
sf::Texture backgroundTex;
sf::Texture coinTex;
sf::Texture Droptex;
public:
//declare sprites
sf::Sprite player;
sf::Sprite background;
sf::Sprite coin;
sf::Sprite Dropper;

```
spritesAndTextures()
{
    cout << "spritesAndTextures Constructor" << endl;

    //load textures
    playerTex.loadFromFile("images/player.png");
    coinTex.loadFromFile("images/coin.png");
    backgroundTex.loadFromFile("images/background.jpg");

    //set textures
    player.setTexture(playerTex);
    background.setTexture(backgroundTex);
    coin.setTexture(coinTex);

    //sprite and texture properties
    player.scale(2, 2);
    background.setScale(1.0f, 1.25f);
    coin.setScale(0.25f, 0.25f);
    background.setPosition(1.0, -40.0f);
    playerTex.setSmooth(true);
    backgroundTex.setSmooth(true);
    coinTex.setSmooth(true);

    //dropper
    Droptex.loadFromFile("images/player.png");
    Dropper.setTexture(Droptex);
    Dropper.scale(sf::Vector2f(0.04, 0.04));

}

~spritesAndTextures()
{
    cout << "spritesAndTextures Destructor" << endl;
}
```

};

Debug Stack -

```
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\migep\Desktop\OOSD_Group_Game\x64\Debug\sfml-graphics-d-2.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\migep\Desktop\OOSD_Group_Game\x64\Debug\sfml-system-d-2.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\migep\Desktop\OOSD_Group_Game\x64\Debug\sfml-window-d-2.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DXCore.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
The thread 0x1ae8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\directxdatabasehelper.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AppXDeploymentClient.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll'
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll'
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AppXDeploymentClient.dll'
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\u0355756.inf_amd64_5146fc3a012e7afa\B354291\atig6pxx.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\u0355756.inf_amd64_5146fc3a012e7afa\B354291\atio6axx.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxva2.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\u0355756.inf_amd64_5146fc3a012e7afa\B354291\atig6txx.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\atiadlxx.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dinput8.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\InputHost.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. 
'OOSD_Group_Game.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEEB626B2F (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in OOSD_Group_Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000028.
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  Likeliest explanation is that in your code you have passed bad parameters/data into sfml.

Comment: Looks like a null pointer used to access a member. When it crashes in the debugger the call stack may be useful to try and find where in your code it came from.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have added some code, my apologies

Comment: @RetiredNinja I believe I have added the call stack